# Why is the French accent so different from other Romance accents?

Tags: historical-linguistics, pronunciation, french, romance-languages

In terms of pronounciation, the general French accent is very different from the Italian, Spanish or Romanian ones.

For example: many conventional sounds in Romance langauges (i.e. /r/ or /j/) are often absent or used differently in French.

What exactly differentiates the French accent from other Romance accents, and how has it become so distinct?

Comment: This question seems to be too broad. You may need to clarify "so different" and "so distinct". Also the term of "accent" is applicable only in case of speaking another language. Did you mean French native speakers' accent when they speak English?

Comment: /j/ is not really a “conventional sound in Romance languages” that differs in French. Original /j/ has changed to various other pronunciations in all the Romance languages (French and Portuguese /ʒ/, Spanish /x/, Italian /dʒ/… don't know enough about Romanian offhand), and a secondary /j/ has arisen from other sources. /r/ is notoriously unstable in Europe, too, not just in the Romance languages (German dialects include /r ɾ ɹ ʁ/, and English has at least three different ones, too), and even French does also dialectally have /r/ in the south.

Comment: Like most "why" questions about language, the whole of the answer is "because". It is true that French has undergone considerably more sound changes than most (probably, all, but I'm not certain) other Romance langauges, but nobody can tell you why that should have been the case.

Comment: I have to protest here a bit that this was marked *too broad*.  There are many worse (repeated, tautological or pointless) questions asked in this forum.  There are certainly concrete answers to the question of why French is an atypical modern Romance language, in terms of pronunciation too.  And if we don't know why the pronunciation happened (ie not due to substrate), that's a useful answer.  And we do know roughly when.

Comment: I think that this question was a very good one and it has an even better answer: French has undergone many more pronunciation changes because it originated from Latin that was newly learned by completely different tribes, the Germanic tribes, while all other Romance languages were basically developed by speakers whose ancestors were using Latin at all times!